# boos::asio async_wait seems to be blocking

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-asio

I was learning boost asio documentation.I came across this `deadline_timer` example.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>


/*This timer example shows a timer that fires once every second.*/

void print(const boost::system::error_code& e, boost::asio::deadline_timer* t, int* count)
{
    if (*count < 5)
    {   
        std::cout << *count << std::endl;
        ++(*count);

        t->expires_at(t->expires_at() + boost::posix_time::seconds(1));

        t->async_wait(boost::bind(print,boost::asio::placeholders::error, t, count));
    }   
}

int main()
{
    boost::asio::io_service io; 

    int count = 0;

    boost::asio::deadline_timer t(io, boost::posix_time::seconds(10));

    auto myfunc = boost::bind(print, boost::asio::placeholders::error, &t ,&count);
    t.async_wait(myfunc);

    std::cout << "async wait " << std::endl;

    io.run();

    std::cout << "Just called io.run() " << std::endl;                                                                                                                                                             

    std::cout << "Final count is " << count << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The `async_wait()` function seems to be blocking (i.e waiting for the 10 second timer to expire)

The output from the above program is as follows.

```
async wait 
0
1
2
3
4
Just called io.run() 
Final count is 5
```

I would expect an async_wait() to create a separate thread and wait for the timer to expire there meanwhile executing the main thread.

i.e I would expect the program to print

```
Just called io.run() 
Final count is 5
```

while waiting for the timer to expire.? Is my understanding wrong?

This is my understanding of async_wait(). This implementation looks more like a `blocking wait`. Is my understanding wrong? What am I missing?

Comment: What is the output you're expecting to take place? Everything looks like it's happening in the correct order, from my perspective.

Comment: @Xirema - please see my edit to question above.I have explained what I would expect to happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `async_wait` function isn't blocking, `run` is. That's `run`'s job. If you don't want a thread to block in the io_service's processing loop, don't have that thread call `run`.

The `async_wait` function doesn't create any threads. That would make it expensive and make it much harder to control the number of threads servicing the io_service.

Your expectation is unreasonable because returning from `main` terminates the process. So who or what would wait for the timer?

Answer (score 5):

The `io.run();` statement is the key to explaining the difference between the output you're getting and the output you're expecting.

In the ASIO framework, any asynchronous commands need to have a dedicated thread to run the callbacks upon. But because ASIO is relatively low-level, it expects you to provide the thread yourself.

As a result, what you're doing when you call `io.run();` within the main thread is to specify to the framework that you intend to run all asynchronous commands on the main thread. That's acceptable, but that also means that the program will block on `io.run();`.

If you intend the commands to run on a separate thread, you'll have to write something like this:

```
std::thread run_thread([&]() {
    io.run();
});

std::cout << "Just called io.run() " << std::endl;                                                                                                                                                             

std::cout << "Final count is " << count << std::endl;

run_thread.join();

return 0;
```

Comment: @liv2hak I wrote a [lambda expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) to quickly model the creation of a thread without going through the effort of constructing and binding a function pointer. In this case, the `[&]` is indicating that any variables I reference inside the lambda that aren't locally declared are meant to be captured, and specifically, captured by reference (as opposed to `[=]`, which would have meant I wanted to capture by value).